# How to do this particular selective masking in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 2d NumPy arrays. I need to mask array 2 on array 1 in such a way that, whatever non zero value present in array2 should get replaced in array1, but others should remain the same.
I need the function selective mask where I can input this two 2d arrays and it returns output.
eg:

```py
array1=np.array([[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[3,3,3]])
array2=n.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[7,8,9]])
result_array=selective_mask(array1,array2)
```

result array should be `[[1,2,3],[0,0,0],[7,8,9]]`, as you can see only the elements 7,8,9 got switched as that was only the non zero elements in array2.

Comment: Do you have a working solution which is not fast enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution.
I used `np.where`

```
np.where(array2!=0,array2,array1)
```